# Multiple Data flows vs all Transformations in one

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I am new to Azure data factory and not all familiar with the back-end processing that run behind the scenes. I am wondering if there is a performance impact to running couple of data flows in parallel when compared to having all the transformations in one data flow.

I am trying to stage some data with a not exists transformation. i have to do it for multiple tables. when i test ran two data flows in parallel the clusters were brought up together for both the data flows simultaneously. But I am not sure if this the best approach to distribute the loading of tables across couple of data flows or to have all the transformations in one data flow

Answer (score 1):

1: If you execute data flows in a pipeline in parallel, ADF will spin-up separate Spark clusters for each based on the settings in your Azure Integration Runtime attached to each activity.

2: If you put all of your logic inside a single data flow, then it will all execute in that same job execution context on a single Spark cluster instance.

3: Another option is to execute the activities in serial in the pipeline. If you have set a TTL on the Azure IR configuration, then ADF will reuse the compute resources (VMs) but you will still a brand-new Spark context for each execution.

All are valid practices and which one you choose should be driven by your requirements for your ETL process.

No. 3 will likely take the longest time to execute end-to-end. But it does provide a clean separation of operations in each data flow step.

No. 2 could be more difficult to follow logically and doesn't give you much re-usability.

No. 1 is really similar to #3, but you run them all in parallel. Of course, not every end-to-end process can run in parallel. You may require a data flow to finish before starting the next, in which case you're back in #3 serial mode.

Comment: Hi @Markkromer thanks for the reply, I was thinking of creating a pipeline  with couple of data flows to stage the delta records. then call the data flows-pipeline in another pipeline to then execute store procedures in a serial manner. I believe this should achieve my ETL goals. would you recommend this approach from a performance and cost point of view ?